# When to use a member pointer variable in C++

Tags: c++

I have a question about C++ design/implementation for best practice. I find myself having trouble deciding whether a member variable should be a pointer or not a pointer.

Lets say I have a class like this:

```
class Person{
     public:
        string name;
        int age;
        Child c;
};
```

Lets say that I want the "Child c" to be dynamic. Lets say that upon the creation of a "Person", I am not sure whether or not the Person has a child. It may be that the Person does have a child and does not have a child. And with this in mind, I want to be able to check in the code if the Person **has** a child.

Is it better to declare it as "Child* c" or "Child c"?

Given this, is it better to

```
class Person{
         public:
            string name;
            int age;
            Child* c;
    };
```

Comment: You shouldn't use raw pointers in general. Pick one suitable [from these](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)!

Comment: This really depends on your design. Is `Child` particularly expensive to copy? Is it possible for other `Person` objects to access your `Child`? Are you only going to have one `Child` object or is it possible to have several of them?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: An owning smart pointer might not be appropriate. Should a Child die because the parent does?

Comment: @OP, I'd go for `(std::experimental|boost)::optional<Child> c`.

Comment: @FredLarson `<memory>` also contains `weak_ptr` which could be suitable for an observable pointer if the child is dynamically allocated.

Comment: @FredLarson: Using a `std::weak_pointer` would solve that, right?

Comment: From what I've been led to believe, `weak_ptr` shouldn't be used for that, rather only in conjunction with `shared_ptr`. I really haven't put in the time/effort to learn how to effectively use it, though.

Comment: @Chnossos: Yes, which must be made from a `std::shared_ptr`. It could be the right answer.

Comment: @chris: Yes, the `Child` itself would be declared with a `shared_ptr`, and the parent would have a `weak_ptr` reference to it. Anyways, this is all semantics on an example, so we should probably leave it at that.

Comment: @FredLarson That's why I said _'pick one appropriate'_. The non owning are well listed there!

Comment: I personally like raw pointers because i have complete control over them. the problem of course is much much easier for bugs to happen. If your careful enough and have appropriate unit tests, then its not such a problem, at least in my own experiences

Comment: sorry, i don't always use raw pointers of course. i'll use smart pointers any time the objects are not part of a system that keeps track of references

Comment: @iedoc _'I personally like raw pointers because i have complete control over them'_ Usually the problem using them as references is you ***haven't control***, especially not over their lifetime/validity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Introduction

If you want *Person* to either have a child, or not, there's really no question; you cannot declare *Person* to have a data-member of type *Child*. By having a child as data-member, *Person* will inconditionally have one as a member.

You can of course solve this by having a *pointer-to-Child*, then the *Person* will either be able to refer to a *Child* if such is present, or have a `nullptr` in the *pointer-to-Child* to express that no such child exists.

---

#### Further thoughts

You need to decide whether Person should *own* a child, or just be able to refer to one.

- If you decide that *Person* is the **owner** of its child, you are recommended to express this *ownership* through a **[`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)**, this will also ease handling the lifetime of said child.
- If you want Person to share a child between other instances (or other some other piece of code), use a **[`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)**.
- If you just want Person to be able to refer to a child (no ownership at all), and being able to change what child (if any child at all) a Person refers to; use a raw-pointer.
- If you want *Person* to be able to refer to a child already in existance, from the start- until the end of its lifetime, use a reference initalized by the constructor of *Person*.

---

#### What if I really want a child as data-member of every Person?

You could have `Child` contain some sort of information that would tell you about its inner state, having either *"alive"* or *"is not alive"* but this is not as clear in terms of expressiveness, or express the *"has a child"* inside *Person* using a similar method.

Comment: Depending on the class you could have something like `Child::NonExistent`, or some other contrived way of being able to have a normal `Child c`, but yeah.

Comment: @chris such thoughts were included in the post during the last edit, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @FilipRoséen-refp for the thorough answer! By any chance do you have any good code examples of each case? Is there a website you'd recommend? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are not appropriate here at all, and you do not need dynamic allocation to obtain an "optional" member.

It is better to use [a `boost::optional<Child>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

If you *were* to use a pointer, you'd use a smart pointer that manages the lifetime of the pointee for you.

Comment: Is the `std::experimental` version mature enough to be worth mentioning ?

Comment: @Chnossos: I haven't tried it but I'd have to imagine that it'd depend on your compiler. `boost::optional` does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a non-pointer attribute you bind the lifecycle of that object to the lifecyle of the containing object.

If you don't desire that, then you need a pointer.

Alternatively you could have some sort of container (e.g. std::vector) where to store the attribute... but that would imply semantics of (0..*) instead of (0..1)

Other reasons for preferring/requiring a pointer:

1. Hiding details of implementation (use a pointer to a parent abstract class) or having the ability to store objects from different parts of a hierarchy.
2. Avoiding a circular reference.

What sort of pointer is up to you. If you want to avoid trouble, use either [shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). 
If you use raw pointers, then you should be concerned about the ownership of the allocated object, i.e. who is in charge of allocating it and *most important* who is responsible for deallocating it.

Comment: `boost.optional` is (0..1). It is designed precisely for this, and works very well.